# jQuery Booklet plugin stop auto play after one flip

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the jQuery Booklet plugin to flip page in my application. I need that the flip will be done automatically (without the user input) and will stop exactly after one flip. 
I implemented the auto play according to the instruction

```
$(function() {
$('#mybook').booklet({
    auto: true
});
```

and now I want to add the "pause" call but in the instruction page 
http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/demos/auto
there is only example where the pause is **done by clicking on the pause link**

```
   $(function() {
$('#mybook').booklet({
    auto: true,
    play: '#play',
    pause: '#pause'
});
```

});

**and I need it to be done without a user input**.
I will appreciate your help in this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create your book

$(function() {
        $('#mybook').booklet({);
    });

This will flip the first page. if you have more that 2 pages.

$('#mybook').booklet("next");

**OR**

you can set timeout if you want some delay
for example

setTimeout(function (){
$('#mybook').booklet("next");
}, 1000);

this will give it a one second delay before flipping the page 
for more info

http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/demos/methods

Comment: I need that the flip effect will stop after the first page flip without any user input,(the flip is accruing without the user input with the auto:true property)